# Exporting Data Grid to PDF

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0, datagridview, itext

Hello I have created basic Grid View to Pdf in my controller what I am having problem with is hot split the result into two lines instead of one. 
I want City, State, and Zip to be on new line.

Thank You.

`public FileStreamResult GetPdf(int? id) {

```
        List<Requisition> all = new List<Requisition>();

        using (ClinlabEntities dc = new ClinlabEntities()) {
            all = dc.Requisitions.Where(reqId => reqId.ReqId == id).ToList<Requisition>();
        }

        WebGrid grid = new WebGrid(all);
        string gridHtml = grid.GetHtml(

        columns: grid.Columns(
        grid.Column("FirstName", " "),
        grid.Column("LastName", " "),
        grid.Column("Address", " "),
        grid.Column("City", " "),
        grid.Column("State", " "),
        grid.Column("Zip", " ")
        )).ToString();

        string exportData = String.Format("<html><head>{0}</head><body>{0}</body></html>", "<style>table(border-spacing:00px; font-size:8px; border-collapse:seperate;)</style>", gridHtml);
        var bytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(exportData);
        using (var input = new MemoryStream(bytes)) {
            var output = new MemoryStream();
            var document = new iTextSharp.text.Document(PageSize.LETTER, 130, 0, 50, 0);
            var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, output);
            writer.CloseStream = false;
            document.Open();
            var xmlWorker = iTextSharp.tool.xml.XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance();
            xmlWorker.ParseXHtml(writer, document, input, System.Text.Encoding.UTF7);
            document.Close();
            output.Position = 0;
            return new FileStreamResult(output, "Application/Pdf");
        }
    }
}
```

}[image]`

Comment: Ignoring iText for a brief moment, how would you do it in HTML/CSS?

Comment: Hi Chris. I am a very beginner so I am not quietly sure...

Comment: The reason I asked you this was because you need to solve this in HTML and CSS *before* you give it to iText. However, if you don't know how to do this then is it safe to assume that you don't actually need a `Grid` in the first place? Can you bypass the entire HTML pipeline and just use something like `document.Add(new Paragraph("Hello"));`?

Comment: Chris, Yes I was able to add hello and it works! I appreciate your help.